# React Native: 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.headers['set-cookie']')'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a React Native application and have cloned a fresh copy of a previously working project, however upon running the application it runs very briefly before returning the following error. I am clueless as to what is causing it.

[image]

EDIT 1:

Code block:

```
if (this.withCredentials && (response.headers['set-cookie'] || response.headers['set-cookie2'])) {
XMLHttpRequest.cookieJar
    .setCookies(response.headers['set-cookie'] || response.headers['set-cookie2']);
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the code (code block) that invoking this error?

Comment: Have added on to the initial post

Comment: Any success here? Happens to me only on iOS in release build